# Spring Data QuerydslBinderCustomizer MongoDb List querying

Tags: mongodb, binding, spring-data, querydsl

I have 2 documents mapped to MongoDb

```
    @Document
    public class Blog {
        @Id
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
....
```

and

```
    @Document
    public class Article {
        @Id
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String author;
...
```

I'm using QuerydslBinderCustomizer for binding. When I`m binding for example String.class all works perfectly:

```
/blogs?name=blog_name&id=3409845jk45


public interface BlogRepository extends MongoRepository<Blog, String>
        , QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Blog>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QBlog> {

    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QBlog root) {

        bindings.bind(String.class)
            .first((StringPath path, String value) -> {
                return path.eq(value);
             });
    }
}
```

But I can`t find out how to bind something like this:

```
/blogs?name=blog_name&articles.name=nice_article
```

for querying in Mongo something like this:

```
Predicate filterBlog = qBlog.name.eq(parameters.getFirst("name"))
                .and(qBlog.articles.any().author.eq(parameters.getFirst("articles.name")));

return (List<Blog>) blogRepository.findAll(filterBlog );
```